# javascript function running out of order

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message, anonymous-function

In a Chrome Extension, I am trying to get saved information from the option page and use it in a content script. I am passing a message to the background script to get it. I have surrounded the sendMessage in the content script in a temporary function(I think that's what it's called) so that I could store the color outside of it. Unfortunatly it leads to things running about out of order. The output from the code below is:

> 3red
>
> 1red
>
> 2blue

I assume this has something to deal with the fact that I have created a temporary function.

**Content_script.js:**

```
    (function(){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "favColor"},
             function(response) {
                 console.log("1"+color);
                 color = response.data;
                 console.log("2"+color);
             }
        )
     })(color);

console.log("3"+color);
a.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

**Background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getLocalStorage")
      sendResponse({data: localStorage[request.key]});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

Comment: The first issue I see is that your `onMessage.addListener` expects a to receive a call with 3 arguments, but you're only passing two: the object and anonymous callback function.  You should be passing the `sender` as the second argument

Comment: @NuclearGhost In this case what should sender be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the chrome runtime is running asynchronously. So when you execute that first function, it won't log those 1 and 2 messages until after the response is sent. It registers the callback and proceeds with the rest of the script. Since it takes a little bit of time for the runtime to respond, even though it may be fast, it won't receive a message back until after it's already logged 3 to the console.

Comment: So does that mean the console logs are slowing down the whole function so a.style.backgroundColor will get the wrong value?

Comment: It's not that they're slowing it down, because they occur *after* the response comes in. It's the chrome.runtime message passing that is slow. So you're going to want to put the `a.style.backgroundColor` inside the response callback.